# What is the main use of ResponseTypeAttribute in Asp.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

You might think this question may be repeated but i couldn't find any useful answer for my question.

This is my controller action

```
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType(typeof(UserInputModel))]
public IHttpActionResult GetUsers(UserInputModel userModel)
{        
    if(adminBao.GetUsers(userModel)==null)
    {
       return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(adminBao.GetUsers(userModel));
}
```

What difference in the output does it make when I remove  `[ResponseType(typeof(UserInputModel))]`

I know this is used to hint the web api about the generic return type...But what impact it make in the response?

Can some one please help me to understand about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what impact it make in the response?

It has no impact on the actual response. It is mainly for documentation purposes.

Its main purpose is so that the `ApiExplorer` knows what type the Action returns when an abstraction is used in the action definition.

The explorer would not be able to determine that from `HttpResponseMessage` or `IHttpActionResult` or one of their derivatives.

That way when generating documentation it can show proper types.

[ResponseTypeAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.description.responsetypeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx)

> Use this to specify the entity type returned by an action when the
>   declared return type is `HttpResponseMessage` or `IHttpActionResult`. The
>   ResponseType will be read by [ApiExplorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.description.apiexplorer(v=vs.118).aspx) when generating
>   [ApiDescription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.description.apidescription(v=vs.118).aspx).